# Capture select option value with Angular 6+

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

This might be pathetic of me, but I cannot seem to console.log the selected value of a Select with Angular 5+ using the Material css. Long story short, all it should do is just return the value of the selected option and print it in the console.log

html

```
<mat-select (change)='filter(element)'>
      <mat-option value='2018'>2018</mat-option>
      <mat-option value='2017'>2017</mat-option>
      <mat-option value='2016'>2016</mat-option>
      <mat-option value='2015'>2015</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Typescript

```
filter(e:Element)
  {
    console.log(e)
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `selectionChange` instead of `change` event. `<mat-select (selectionChange)='filter($event)'>`. Also you can pass `$event` instead of `element`. From the docs `https://material.angular.io/components/select/api`

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: That worked. Although I had to get rid of the Element tag, but it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use ngModel like

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (selectionChange)="printVal()">
<mat-option value=''>Select Value</mat-option>
  <mat-option value='2018'>2018</mat-option>
  <mat-option value='2017'>2017</mat-option>
  <mat-option value='2016'>2016</mat-option>
  <mat-option value='2015'>2015</mat-option>
</select>
```

in your ts

```
selectedValue = '';
printVal(){
   console.log(this.selectedValue)
   }
```

Here ngModel is a two-way binding, the selectionChange will fire whenever you select an option

if you want to print the value using event just change the function

Answer (score 0):

1. do this on your template file.

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"  >
   <option  value="All" >All</option>
   <option  value="Specialist" >Specialist</option>
   <option  value="General practitioner">General practitioner</option>
</select>
```

2. on you .ts file

```
 onChange(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
```

Comment: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ngtsc(2339)
template.component.ts(6, 39): Error occurs in the template of component TemplateComponent.